# Java variable initialization and if statement

Tags: java, variables, initialization

Jcreator says variable `big` might not have been initialized `if(big%2==0)`.
Then I change `"int big"` to `"int big=0"`, it works. I have initialized `big` in the first two if statements before `if(big%2==0)`, why did this happen?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Large
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {   
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        int number1,number2;
        int big;
        System.out.println("Enter 2 values");
        number1=in.nextInt();
        number2=in.nextInt();
        if(number1>number2)
            big=number1;
        if(number2>=number1)
            big=number2;
        if(big%2==0)
            System.out.println("even");
        if(big%2==1)
            System.out.println("odd");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It isn't able to perform logic at compilation that seems obvious to you. Use an `else`

```
 if(number1>number2)
   big=number1;
 else /* if(number2>=number1) <-- because, this is a new expression */
   big=number2;
```

Or a `ternary`,

```
big = (number1>number2) ? number1 : number2;
```

Or [Math.max(int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max%28int,%20int%29),

```
big = java.lang.Math.max(number1, number2);
```

Comment: @JoshM Good call. Added it.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable was declared, but not initialized.

The initialization of the variable states what its value is. You shouldn't use a variable until its value has been set.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables require explicit initialization or assignment before being used.

The compiler doesn't know that your logic means the variable must be assigned, it only knows there are a couple of if statements where the variable *can* be initialized, but there is a possibility that it won't if neither if condition is true.

Because your second if condition is the opposite if the first, change it to an else:

```
if(number1>number2)
    big=number1;
else
    big=number2;
```

The compiler will now be happy that no matter the condition, the variable must be assigned a value.

---

Consider using a ternary for a one line declaration and assignment:

```
int big = number1 > number2 ? number1 : number2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work.

```
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    int number1,number2;
    int big;
    System.out.println("Enter 2 values");
    number1=in.nextInt();
    number2=in.nextInt();
    if(number1>number2) {
        big=number1;
    } else if(number2>number1) {
        big=number2;
    } else {
        big = number1;
    }
    if(big%2==0)
        System.out.println("even");
    if(big%2==1)
        System.out.println("odd");
```